# indexing array in mongodb chat design

Tags: mongodb, indexing, chat

I want to design a simple chat in mongodb.

the conversation schema is like

```
{
    conversation_id:  { type: ObjectId },
    time:  { type: Date },
    type: { type: String , enum:['direct','group']},
    members: [{ type: ObjectId }],
    total_messages:  { type: Number },
}
```

.

Usually there are two simple type of conversation, one is direct chat, another is group chat. In the direct chat, the number of members is 2 people while group member has more than 2 people.

For query a conversation of any user, using $in is ok

```
    {
        conversation_id: 12345,
        time: time,
        members: ['user_id1', 'user_id2'],
        total_messages: 2
    }.

  let query = {
    "members":{ $in: body.users } 
  };
```

I want to index the 'members' property in the direct mode in order to speed up the search; and in the group mode , I think it is ok not to index 'members' property in the group mode, since the group member may have ten to hundred people, indexing is too costly.

so my first question is how would I do the array indexing( only 2 elements in the direct chat) to make the search more efficiently.

second question is can I have the separate indexing depending the chat type, direct chat with array indexing and group chat without array indexing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [partial indexes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-partial/) supported by MongoDB. You can index your `members` key and specify a `partialFilterExpression` where `type` value should be `direct`. Something like this:

```
db.collection.createIndex(
   { members: 1 },
   { partialFilterExpression: { type: 'direct' } }
)
```

This command will create an array index, for the `direct` chat type.